# .blend/.blender file upload using codeigniter

Tags: ajax, file-upload, codeigniter-2, blender, blend

I want to upload .blend or .blender file using codeigniter...

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|psd|xls|xlsx|xml|doc|docx|csv|mpeg|mpg|mp3|mpga|pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '5024';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
    echo 'error';
}else{
    print_r($this->upload->data());
}
```

Which Mimes type i m used for blender file extension...